# How is is possible to know how is the size of the log file on MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, size, logfile

I'm a new user of MySQL and I'd like to know how is it possible to know the size of the log file in MySQL 5.7. I'm not asking for the configuration parameter that determine the size of the log file in My.ini (innodb_buffer_pool_size) but the effective log file sizing.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just look at the size of the file in the Operating System?  There are many log files with MySQL (error, audit, binlog, slow, general) but all logs grow in size as they are constantly being written to.  The only way to know the file size is to go to the directory where the log files exists (linux:  /var/log/mysql) and see what size each log is.

Answer (score 0):

You could SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_os_log_written'; for the byte count written since instance START.  These bytes could be appended to an existing log file.  Look at your file sizes from your OS perspective in the file list that should be available.